# Getting JSTL to run within Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, glassfish, jstl

I've been trying to get this to run, but I can't.  I'm using Eclipse Galileo, Tomcat 5.5.23 and have several JSTLs around. My latest try was to use the GlassFish jar file "jstl-impl-1.2.jar". I placed it in Tomcat's shared lib, added it as external jar into my Eclipse project and exported it.

Could anybody tell me, which jars to load in which folder and how to tell it to load in Eclipse?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's very simple to include jstl in your projects, what I do is:

1. Download jstl-1.2.jar (JSP 2.1
   containers only i.e. Tomcat 6,
   otherwise jstl-1.1.jar) from
   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/

    *or* 
   the interfaces (javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar) from http://search.maven.org/#browse|707331597 and the actual implementing classes (javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.2.jar) from http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1002239589.
2. Copy to your project's WEB-INF/lib directory
3. Include the following tags in yours jsp's:

   - <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
   - <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
   - <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
   - <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>

As for eclipse I need to know if your using any framework plugin, I use MyEclipse and it does it automatically for me.

Comment: I do not use any framework plugin; your solution is passed without error shown in Eclipse, but after export, deployment and start I get:
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ValueExpression"

Comment: That could mean a lot of things Alex, I'll start by verifying if Java versions are the same from development environment and production environment.  Also if there's already libraries in tomcat/common/lib.  Are you using Tomcat 6?  Try copying your el-api.jar and jstl-1.2.jar from your project to your production server's --> tomcat/common/lib

Comment: I got it now: it is really a version problem as you stated in your first sentence. using tomcat 5.5 you have to use a jstl with version 1.1 (I downloaded it from jakarta taglibs)

Comment: Glad someone had an answer for this. Been chasing this exact problem with legacy components all day! Thanks for clearing it up, guys.

Comment: Download link doesnt work. See this page for downloading different versions of JSTL jar http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Hi @Juparave can you explain what the four includes do? For example if I don't want to use sql features can I not include the last?

Comment: HOW IS THIS VERY SIMPLE!?!?  None of the steps you have outlines work.

Answer (score 4):

Another method is shown here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

In short, download jstl.jar from here:

http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar

and drop it in your WEB-INF/lib dir

and add the line:

```
<%@  taglib  prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  %>
```

in your jsp file.

(don't forget to do F5 and clean and build after that)