# Servelet set attribute doesn't print in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have set a List of book and set to the request.setAttribute("booksa", allbooks); and in jsp i try to print the List in table but no values printed only the empty table.

This is my Servelet

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    String userPath = request.getServletPath();

     if (userPath.equals("/index")) {
        // TODO: Implement category request

       userPath = "/index";

    }
     else if (userPath.equals("/books"))
     {
        List<Book> allbooks = bookFacade.findAll();

        userPath = "/books";
        request.setAttribute("booksa", allbooks);
        //System.out.print(allbooks);
     }
     else
     {

     }

     String url = userPath + ".jsp";

      try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my Book.jsp page

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body>




<table border="1">
    <!-- column headers -->
    <tr>
        <td>ISBN</td>
        <td>TITLE</td>
        <td>PRICE</td>
        <td>YEARS</td>
        <td>LANGUAGE</td>
    </tr>


<!-- column data -->

    <c:forEach var="vehicle" items="${booksa}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${vehicle.isbn}"  /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${vehicle.title}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${vehicle.price}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${vehicle.years}"  /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${vehicle.languages}"  /></td>
            </tr>

   </c:forEach>
</table>   
</body>
```

But when i redirect to this page the view page source show like this

```
<!-- column data -->

    <c:forEach var="vehicle" items="[ejb.Book[ isbn=SR001 ]]">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value=""  /></td>
                <td><c:out value="" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="" /></td>
                <td><c:out value=""  /></td>
                <td><c:out value=""  /></td>
            </tr>

   </c:forEach>
```

My Book class

```
public Book() {
}

public Book(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public Book(String isbn, String title, double price, int years, String languages) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.years = years;
    this.languages = languages;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getYears() {
    return years;
}

public void setYears(int years) {
    this.years = years;
}

public String getLanguages() {
    return languages;
}

public void setLanguages(String languages) {
    this.languages = languages;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Author> getAuthorCollection() {
    return authorCollection;
}

public void setAuthorCollection(Collection<Author> authorCollection) {
    this.authorCollection = authorCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (isbn != null ? isbn.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Book)) {
        return false;
    }
    Book other = (Book) object;
    if ((this.isbn == null && other.isbn != null) || (this.isbn != null && !this.isbn.equals(other.isbn))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ejb.Book[ isbn=" + isbn + " ]";
}
```

}

values are coming to page but i don't know how to print please give me a help

Comment: Have you printed the list before passing it to the jsp ?

Comment: when i debug the jsp page booksa have filled with database value but i don't know how to print

Comment: show your `Book` class and have you added the jstl tag library ?

Comment: how to add the jstl tag library

Comment: Thanx i added the jstl library and it works

Comment: your welcome ! . i will add this as my answer . feel free to upvote and accept it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the following line in your JSP, in the beginning. That should solve your issue

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not added the `jstl` to your build path , just add from the references here ,

1.[Adding jstl support](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-jstl-on-my-jsps.html)

2.[Getting JSTL to run within Tomcat and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521257/getting-jstl-to-run-within-tomcat-and-eclipse)

hope this helps!!