# Jstl not adding correct to Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse (Juno)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have seen several Tutorials and post where they show you how to add the Jstl.rar to be able to use it with JSP Files. But I'm not havving any luck

This is what I did

1. Create Dynamic Web Project
2. Download the Jstl 1.2. from Apache came with:
   taglibs-standad-impl-1.2.5jar,taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar,taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar,taglibs-standard-compat-1.2.5.jar
3. Add jar files under /WEB-INF/lib
4. Create jsp file and add <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

It gives me an error it cannot find the tag description <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

I look at these articles but they tell you different ways to fix it but they are not working. Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to learn this but I'm struggling because of this

[About Jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

[Getting jstl to run with tomcat and eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521257/getting-jstl-to-run-within-tomcat-and-eclipse)

I also tried going to properties ->Java Build Path-> Libraries. And add a new user library and under that user library add all the jar files but didnt work either. Am i missing some confugiration on the web.xml file. Any help please ?

Comment: Does the JSP Editor's content assist in the URI attribute offer anything? Also, try closing and reopening the project; things may have gotten confused with the ordering.

Comment: @nitind Thanks for taking the time! . No it does not assist with any suggestions. Do I need to make any changes on th eweb.xml file. Kind of like setting up a path so its able to see the jar file ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, no, not as long as the Web App classpath container is on the Java Build Path. The JSP support scans all of those jars for .tld files.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this set of jars--can you double-check where the TLDs are in those jars?

Comment: @nitind how do i do that? because i only see the .jar files nothing else. Which ones do you suggest to use instead ?

Comment: You should be able to expand them in the Package/Project Explorer, to show you the classes and other contained resources, or use a .zip file tool of some kind to get the list of files they contain.

Comment: @nitind Thanks for still helping. I got it to work ! I use the jstl API and implementation from https://jstl.java.net/download.html. and instead of just placing the files under /WEB-INF/lib. I right click on that folder when on the explorer on Eclipse and import both jar files. Now it Works!. Thanks for the help !