# How can i create a for loop in a jsp file in order to make multiple rows in a table?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

This is the current code i am trying to use. I was looking up online and <% and %> escape in order to use something like a for loop. So far <% is just printed on the page.

```
out.print("<table border = \"1\"> <%for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) { <tr><th>i</th></tr> }%>");
```

Comment: Put one out.print outside the loop for the table header, and a second out.print inside the loop.  Don't try to make the loop part of the print call.

Comment: Use [displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/)

Comment: Can you show me an example @PaulKienitz I don't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [c:forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html).You can try something like this

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${itemList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${item}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

### See Also

- [How to create table dynamically using count and JSTL ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783572/how-to-create-table-dynamically-using-count-and-jstl-foreach)

Comment: I have tried that, nothing works. Do i need to import anything? Also this is being uploaded onto a web server and displayed, will it work just like that?

Comment: you need to use jstl library to make it work.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521257/getting-jstl-to-run-within-tomcat-and-eclipse